# can you anyone please explain what is the use of viewport in the header.php file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have seen this code  in my header. php file, i don't know what is the use of this tag. They also mentioned initial scale=1.0 like that so can you anyone explain me what the use of that code.

Comment: im sorry, i can't get you patrick

Comment: Meaning show a little effort that you actually tried to figure it out yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's used to set the initial scale of the layout.  If the initial scale is set to 1, then the layout will be viewed at a scale of 1:1 (no zooming).  It can be adjusted as well as changed to a set width.